# What email management software to use for bigger projects on Linux?

Tags: linux, email

I am trying to find some management system for project I am starting and it has already many e-mails. We want to start full free support by e-mails. It means some ticket system for e-mails like I saw in other companies which somehow order emails to tickets and automatically answers them with message that it will be answered in a few days or so.

I saw in many projects emails with subjects like `Ticket #23986522` or `[Ticket#2010070610102874] RapidShare` for rapidshare support.

So again my question what is the best/reliable managements system for handling many e-mails for free or at least for minimum price (open source in best case)? I have my own domain and e-mails. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All though it sounds like a shopping question, which is off topic. I suggest you have a look at [Request Tracker](http://bestpractical.com/rt/).

A lot of people use it and it comes with support. I wrote a brief overview and an installation guide on my [blog](http://cloud101.eu/blog/2012/03/01/request-tracker-4-what-is-it-how-to-install-it-on-debian-squeeze/).

Comment: It is not shopping question - just starting some fee project and already have many questions about it in email and I like this email management i saw in some companies.

Comment: A shopping question is a question that asks to give up names of software for a certain service not for the service itself :)

Comment: This system you posted is very extensive and I would like to see some easier way only for e-mails I think - not need names exactly just direction where to look etc.

Comment: Have you tried google?

Comment: I did but there are many and many of them have very high pricing for big companies I just thought about something for email management for small project I do for school nothing big.

Comment: @Dukla: There's a reason why RT does a lot of things -- because you need a lot of features to be able to run a support organisation.  As someone who manages a sizeable support team, my advice is to suck it up and take the time to learn RT (or whatever fully-featured equivalent program you decide to use).  You will use all of its features sooner or later.